# Azure Cosmos DB Emulator Linux image does not start (Error: The evaluation period has expired.)

Tags: docker, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

With the following image `mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest` when attempting to start a container either via:

- Docker Desktop (Windows)
- Or, via the following CLI command (Windows):

```
docker run --name azure-cosmosdb-emulator --memory 2GB --interactive --tty -p 8081:8081 -p 8900:8900 -p 8901:8901 -p 8902:8902 -p 10250:10250 -p 10251:10251 -p 10252:10252 -p 10253:10253 -p 10254:10254 -p 10255:10255 -p 10256:10256 -p 10350:10350 mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator
```

- Or, Docker Desktop (Mac)
- Or, via CLI from the instructions (Mac)
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/linux-emulator?tabs=sql-api%2Cssl-netstd21#run-the-linux-emulator-on-macos

I get the same error in all the above:

```
2022-11-15 16:34:08 Error: The evaluation period has expired.
2022-11-15 16:34:08 ./cosmosdb-emulator: ERROR: PAL initialization failed. Error: 104
```

I've tried to delete the containers/image and pull latest to no avail

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We are looking into this issue and update on the findings by EOD [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-db-emulator-docker/issues/60), the new image needs to get published and it might take couple of days if everything works as expected.

as a workaround until this gets fixed, you can use the image with the tag mongodb , the same features are available

> mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:mongodb

**UPDATE**:

we have published a new image , try with the latest tag

*FROM mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest*

Comment: I tried this using a docker-compose file, make sure you delete the existing image locally first. Now it's back up and running!

Comment: Hi! The issue is back now with the MongoDB emulator. Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 8):

There is a GitHub issue for this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-db-emulator-docker/issues/60

At the moment it does not help to delete and pull the image. It looks like a global issue which only Microsoft can fix by pushing a new image with where the evaluation period is extended.

As a workaround you can set back the system time.

**UPDATE:**
It is fixed now when you pull the latest image. Lets hope we don't run into the same issue again in 178 days (13.05.2023) when the "evaluation period" expires again.